# Find closest row form the triggered element using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need your help to `toggle` closest `row` form the `triggered` element. Please go through the fiddle.

What i want is on clicking Relative title name the `next closest` `tr` with class name `.expandKpi` to be toggled.

I tried with the below script which was worked earlier in another condition.

```
$(".annualViewtbody tr .title").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('row_active');
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.expandKpi').toggle();
});
```

Previously there is no `tr` between the parent `tr` and the `expandKpi` tr.

```css
.expandKpi {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered annualView" style="background:#fff">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dummy Heading</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dummy Heading</th>
          <th class="text-center">JAN</th>
          <th class="text-center">FEB</th>
          <th class="text-center">MAR</th>
          <th class="text-center">APR</th>
          <th class="text-center">May</th>
          <th class="text-center">JUN</th>
          <th class="text-center">JUL</th>
          <th class="text-center">AUG</th>
          <th class="text-center">SEP</th>
          <th class="text-center">Oct</th>
          <th class="text-center">Nov</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dec</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">40%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">3</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title2</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">40%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">20</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title3</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">10%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">100</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title4 </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">10%</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">60</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You are missing a space from the selector, it should be $(".annualView tbody tr .title")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nextAll('tr.expandKpi').first()`, plus you have missed a space is selector:
`annualView tbody ...` :

```js
$(".annualView tbody tr .title").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('row_active');
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr.expandKpi').first().toggle();
});
```

```css
.expandKpi {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered annualView" style="background:#fff">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dummy Heading</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dummy Heading</th>
          <th class="text-center">JAN</th>
          <th class="text-center">FEB</th>
          <th class="text-center">MAR</th>
          <th class="text-center">APR</th>
          <th class="text-center">May</th>
          <th class="text-center">JUN</th>
          <th class="text-center">JUL</th>
          <th class="text-center">AUG</th>
          <th class="text-center">SEP</th>
          <th class="text-center">Oct</th>
          <th class="text-center">Nov</th>
          <th class="text-center">Dec</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">40%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">3</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#00c292"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title2</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">40%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">20</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#fec107"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title3</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">10%<br></td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">100</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#ffa452"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="title">Sample Title4 </td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">10%</td>
          <td rowspan="2" class="text-center">60</td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color:#dd1936"></i></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
          <td class="text-center"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="expandKpi">
   <td colspan="8">
    <div class="block_content">
     Hidden Content
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might suit your needs:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mto9a33/

The simple solution is that jQuery's `next` doesn't skip unneeded elements. ;)

Comment: Thanks Man.. I posted question for one issue and you cleared one more :)

Comment: Once the hidden div opened it was not hiding again.

Comment: Nice. Glad to see it helped! :)